# listbox itemtemplate for selected item

Tags: wpf, listbox, selecteditem, itemtemplate

I am using Listbox with ItemTemplate, and when I select an item from the list, it shows blue background
How can I style the selected item, to be similar to non-selected one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope you are looking for to remove the blue default ListBox selection. That color is coming from the IsSelected DataTrigger on the ListBoxItem style. You can override that by creating a copy of ListBoxItemStyle, which is ListBox.ItemContainerStyle

Just a little more inside information about a ListBox customization. Basically a ListBox customization includes overriding below styles and templates

- ListBox.Style - if you want to change the Way the outer shell looks and feel
- ListBox.ItemTemplate - Set the appropriate DataTemplate to display the Individual properties of a type T, where ListBox.ItemsSource is bind to IEnumerable
- ListBox.ItemsPanel - Set the ItemsPanelTemplate which contains a Panel so that the items get laid out by the panel. By default it is a StackPanel with orientation is vertical.
- ListBox.ItemContainerStyle -  set the style of the ListBoxItem